# "Packages cannot be nested" error in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I want to use SoundFacade class from Adobe. ([Here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Sound_23.html), from [github](https://gist.github.com/ts310/555731)). I simple created an "ActionScript File" and paste all the code. But when I want to compile my app I got following error:

> 1037: Packages cannot be nested.

The only reason I can guess is that the package must somehow put into the project or something.

EDIT:
Even when I just put a simple empty package I got the error:

```
package {

}
```

How to Reproduce the bug?

- Create a new Flex Mobile Project.
- Click New > ActionScript File
- type package { }
- include new package in one your views

code:

```
<fx:Script source="../SoundFacade.as" />
```

You will get the error

Comment: You likely have a syntax error in your package statement at the top of the class. The package statement probably appears twice. Show the package statement(s) at the top of your class, AND specify which directory (relative to your application's project) you've put the class on disk... Someone will then confirm what is wrong :)

Comment: You can also try to check for `{` and `}` matching, I'm not sure, but I think I had similar error because of {}.

Comment: There is no syntax error. Even when I just put an empty package I get the error.

Comment: Pasted code from github, works perfectly fine. Clean you project, it always helps

Comment: Clean did not help. Did you test this yourself out? I added how to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. I was actually unaware of the package naming rule. Here is the answer to this problem: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4299377

> The  tag will insert your
>   SoundFacade.as file into the MXML file (similar to an include in
>   C/C++). That will cause an invalid syntax.
>
> Give your package a name (in this case it should be called SoundFacade
>   because that is the name of the folder it is in) then use the import
>   statement inside your script tag. Make sure you adhere to the
>   recommended file, namespace, package and class naming structure.
>   That's usually a reverse-DNS style: com.adobe.utils.bla.bla.bla.
>
> If package name is blank and the source is in the default folder, you
>   don't need to import it.